# Is there a way to let langchain.memory prefix remove " : " and only add "[INST]" at first and add "[/INST]" on human's history?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, langchain, llama

I am using llama2 and its Prompts has a format to let model know about conversation like this

```
[INST] {First_human_input} [/INST]
{First_model_output}
[INST] {Second_human_input}[/INST]
```

but the memory in langchain default like this

```
Human: First_input
AI: First_output
Human: Second_input
```

Although using the default of langchain ,llama can also know but it will output with "AI:"
I have already try to set ai_prefix and human_prefix but " : " can not remove
Is there have a good way to solve?

Answer (score 1):

ConversationStringBufferMemoryYou can find the class here

```
  your_env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\memory\buffer.py
```

find class name "ConversationStringBufferMemory", in save context function you can find Prefix are assigned here. You can modify this class but this is bad practice. OR You can define custom class and extend "ConversationStringBufferMemory" and overide find save_context

```
            def save_context(self, inputs: Dict[str, Any], outputs: Dict[str, str]) -> None:
                """Save context from this conversation to buffer."""
                if self.input_key is None:
                    prompt_input_key = get_prompt_input_key(inputs, self.memory_variables)
                else:
                    prompt_input_key = self.input_key
                if self.output_key is None:
                    if len(outputs) != 1:
                        raise ValueError(f"One output key expected, got {outputs.keys()}")
                    output_key = list(outputs.keys())[0]
                else:
                    output_key = self.output_key
                human = f"{self.human_prefix}: " + inputs[prompt_input_key]
                ai = f"{self.ai_prefix}: " + outputs[output_key]
                self.buffer += "\n" + "\n".join([human, ai])
```

Comment: Can you expand a bit? I am struggling doing this [INST] mess with Llama2 for a multiturn conversation using a ConversationSummaryBufferMemory

Comment: Overriding the `save_context` method does not work as Pydantic complains that the self.buffer attribute does not exist.

Comment: it would be difficult to implement as I don;t have you exact environment/code details, it will end up with version problem at your end